# Update RecyclerView adapter item without calling OnCreateViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

how to update ReyclerView adapter without make OnCreateViewHolder(...) being called?

Because when i do

`mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifiItemChanged(position)`

it goes inside `OnCreateViewHolder(...)` what i don't want to. The reason why i don't want is because I have expanded item view and `onCreateViewHolder(...)` will reinflate it so make collapsed. I only want to `OnBindViewHolder(...)` being called

Have anyone faced with it?

**UPD:**
Just found that `OnCreateViewHolder(...)` is called only one first time, in all next times it's not being called. What is the reason?
t

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole point of `RecyclerView` : it handle a pool of view holders, which are created once (calling `OnCreateViewHolder()`) then reused (or recycled, hence the view name) as much as possible via `OnBindViewHolder()`.

`OnCreateViewHolder()` is used to create the views, while `OnBindViewHolder` (re)set the views state (like text content, selected state, ...)

It follows that any state associated with an item (like the expanded / collapsed state) should not be stored in the `ViewHolder`. You can for example use a private List in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `boolean isExpanded` to your data objects in your dataset, and then in the `onBindViewHolder` method check whether `isExpanded` is `true`, if so expand the view programmatically. (and ofcourse don't forget to switch the `boolean` when expanding/collapsing the view)